# Error with mystrlen function

Tags: c

I was trying to write out some of the implementations of the string functions available in C. My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>   

char *mystrcpy(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    while(*s1++ = *s2++);
    return s1;
}

int mystrlen(char *s)
{
    int len = 0;
    while(*s != '\0')
    {
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}

int main(void)
{
    char arr = "Hi";
    char arr1[10];
    char arr2[] = "Hello";
    int length;

    mystrcpy(arr1, arr2);
    printf("%s", arr1);

    length = mystrlen(arr);
    printf("%d", length);

    return 0;
}
```

`mystrcpy` works fine, but the other method `mystrlen` does no execute. What could be the error? The following is the program termination note:

> Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minutes, 4 seconds)

Also, there are few warnings related to casts. Is there any place in the code where I should be using any cast?

Comment: In general, it is a good idea to read and eliminate all compiler warnings before posting your question: you may get your fix faster.

Comment: mystrcpy return end of s1, Instead it should return the top.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: How can i make it return the top of string??

Comment: @user1262062 - Keep at the entrance of the function. E.g. `char *mystrcpy(char *s1, char *s2){ char* ret = s1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First, your `mystrlen` has an infinite loop.**

Fixed code:

```
int mystrlen(const char *s)
{
    int len = 0;
    while (*s++ /* increment to next character every loop */ != '\0')
    {
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}
```

Also added `const` since you never change the data referred to by `*s`

**Second, the assignment: `char arr="Hi";` is not valid.**

You are attempting to assign a `char[]` array to a `char` variable. The correct form would be *one* of the following:

```
char arr[]="Hi"; // array syntax
char *arr="Hi";  // pointer syntax
```

Given your invalid `arr` assignment, your runtime error is most likely caused by `mystrlen` attempting to incorrectly deference `arr`.

*What compiler are you using? Most conforming compilers should have caught the second issue. If using GCC, add the `-Wall` flag to your makefile.*

Comment: I am using gcc, but it did not catch this error. Isn't it an error ??

Comment: @user1262062, add `-Wall` flag.

Comment: I am sorry, but what is Wall flag ??

Comment: @user1262062 Add `-Wall` to your GCC command line. It instructs the compiler to display/emit all warnings.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
char arr="Hi"; /* Should have caused compiler warning,
                  as is attempting to assign a char
                  to a char[3]. */
```

should be:

```
char arr[] ="Hi";
```

or:

```
char* arr = "Hi";
```